# Tweetdeck search column incomplete

Tags: search, twitter, tweetdeck

When I add a new search column in Tweetdeck some of the chosen keywords give incomplete search results compared to search results from twitter.com. I tried another Tweetdeck username (for syncing), deleted the search column from the server and tried reinstalling the application. Nothing works. Weird thing is that only a few keywords do not work properly (and I used them before...). Anyone any idea?

Answer (score 1):

There might not be a way around it, the Twitter API can be a little shaky with some less marquee features like searching so the application may not be able to see more than what you can get it to see. Have you tried Twitter searching in another program? If you get the same results in that as you do with Tweetdeck than that is what this is.

Comment: When I search in another Twitter client, for example Mixero, the results are ok and the same as search results from twitter.com. So it has to do with Tweetdeck...